# How to join array based on position and datatype in Python?

Tags: python, arrays

I have a few arrays containing integer and strings. For example:

```
myarray1 = [1,2,3,"ab","cd",4]
myarray2 = [1,"a",2,3,"bc","cd","e",4]
```

I'm trying to combine only the strings in an array that are next to each other. So I want the result to be:

```
newarray1= [1,2,3,"abcd",4]
newarray2= [1,"a",2,3,"bccde",4]
```

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: 1. In python these are called lists. 2. What is `a` in `myarray2` and `newarray2`? A variable called `a` or `"a"`?

Comment: Oops, it should say "a". No variables are in the array.. thanks!

Comment: In the list i mean... sorry... thanks for the terminology clarification... I'm still learning lol.

Comment: I'd like context.  Where does this problem come up in practice?  It's unusual enough that I'm curious.

Comment: It's for an inventory report. Software from a third party vendor generates a txt file (after a batch of items are physically scanned) that needs to go into excel. The problem is that each column in the txt is iterated by spaces at different lengths. Each item has a sku#,batch#,store#, description, and a few other fields. The problem is that the description (like "red hat", "big fluffy dog", each have a different number of spaces... and the description is the 3rd column in. So I'll have ["001","red", "hat", "0323452"] instead of "red hat". We've been asking them for excel output for months.

Comment: On top of it I'm omitting useless headers in the txt that occur on every page and there are 1000s of items on this thing with at least 50 headers. So it's really a temporary script our dept can use to generate a csv without useless info in it. It saves us about 2 hours doing it manually

Answer (score 3):

The `groupby` breaks the list up into runs of strings and runs of integers. The ternary operation joins the groups of strings and puts them into a temporary sequence. The `chain` re-joins the strings and the runs of integers.

```
from itertools import groupby, chain

def joinstrings(iterable):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(
       (''.join(group),) if key else group 
           for key, group in 
              groupby(iterable, key=lambda elem: isinstance(elem, basestring))))
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know you could do that... much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> myarray1 = [1,2,3,"ab","cd",4]
>>> newarray1 = [myarray1[0]]
>>> for item in myarray1[1:]:
...   if isinstance(item, str) and isinstance(newarray1[-1], str):
...     newarray1[-1] = newarray1[-1] + item
...   else:
...     newarray1.append(item)
>>> newarray1
[1, 2, 3, 'abcd', 4]
```

Comment: Very clear and easy to understand also.. especially since I just started learning python. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [1,2,3,"ab","cd",4]
b = [1,a,2,3,"bc","cd","e",4]

def func(a):
    ret = []
    s = ""
    for x in a:
        if isinstance(x, basestring):
            s = s + x
        else:
            if s:
                ret.append(s)
                s = ""
            ret.append(x)
    return ret
print func(a)
print func(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
reduce(lambda x, (tp, it): tp and x + ["".join(it)] or x+list(it), itertools.groupby( myarray1, lambda x: isinstance(x, basestring) ), [])
```

Comment: `chain` is more efficient and more Pythonic than `reduce`, and Python has a ternary operation -- `trueval if condition(x) else falseval`. Don't use the old `and` / `or` hack.